# random.shuffle does not work in transcrypt

Tags: python

I want to use transcrypt to convert a python script into javascript. The script uses 'shuffle' in the python 'random' module.

I boiled the problem down to this example:

```
l = [ '1', '2' ]
from random import shuffle
while True:
   thing = input( 'thing' )
   print( 'before: {}'.format( ' '.join( l )))
   shuffle( l )
   print( 'after: {}'.format( ' '.join( l )))
```

This fails - if I comment out the 'shuffle( l )' line then it runs fine.

Is shuffle not supported?

**example edited so the python is valid - even the previous invalid python generated javascript which runs & shows the problem with 'random'**

I can see the incorrect javascript output:

```
                var _random_integer = function () {
                    if (_index == 0) {
                        _fill_array ();
                    }
                    var y = _array [_index];
                    y ^= y >> 11;
                    y ^= y << 7 & 2636928640;
                    y ^= y << 15 & 4022730752;
                    y ^= y >> 18;
                    _index = __mod__ (_index + 1, 624);
                    return y;
                };

                ...
                    var random = function () {
                    return _random_integer () / _bitmask3;
                };

                ...

(function () {
    var __name__ = '__main__';
    var l = list (['1', '2']);
    var shuffle = __init__ (__world__.random).shuffle;
    while (true) {
        var thing = input ('thing');
        print ('before: {}'.format (' '.join (l)));
        shuffle (l);
        print ('after: {}'.format (' '.join (l)));
    }
```

I am no javascript expert, but it seems clear to me that this line:

```
var shuffle = __init__ (__world__.random).shuffle;
```

is going to generate a run-time error when 'random' is found to be a simple function.

***EDIT*** I worked around the problem by implementing my own shuffle function (well, I nicked it from the python library and hacked it till it worked):

```
l = [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]

from random import randint

def shuffle( l ):
    n = len( l )
    for i in reversed( range( n )):
        if i == n - 1: continue
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = randint( i + 1, n - 1 )
        l[i], l[j] = l[j], l[i]

while True:
    thing = input( '>' )
    shuffle( l )
    print( ' '.join( l ))
```

Comment: from looking at the javascript that the 'random' module in python is taken to be a javascript function which returns a random number. The produced code, which attempts to get '.shuffle' from this, is presumably crashing the runtime script:

    var shuffle = __init__ (__world__.random).shuffle;

Comment: I can see the 'random' function in the output javascript:

    var random = function () {
        return _random_integer () / _bitmask3;
    };

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change your `print` to make it work:

```
l = [1, 2]
from random import shuffle
while True:
    thing = input( 'thing' )
    print( 'before:',  l)
    shuffle( l )
    print( 'after:', l)
```

The method `join()` expects a list of strings, not integers.
But `print()` already does what you wantfor your output.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. You are quite right about my python being incorrect. However, as I said in an above comment, it still produces valid javascript. The underlying problem I am stuck on is still that I get a 'random' function in the output javascript, and not a 'random' module which I can derefence to get a 'shuffle' function.

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code, I get the error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found` and I get it whether or not I comment out the call to `shuffle()`. I wouldn't say that that "runs fine". It doesn't run at all. That is because you are trying to `join()` a list of integers and `join()` wants a list of strings. Your problem has nothing to do with `shuffle()`.

Change your list definition to this:

```
l = ["1", "2"]
```

and the rest of your code really will run fine.

Comment: Oops thanks you are quite right. However, my code example may be invalid python but it does produce valid javascript!

When run in the webpage it produces this output:
before: 1 2
after: 1 2
thing
before: 1 2
after: 1 2
thing
before: 1 2
after: 1 2
thing